# Avoid manual Ajax calls when authorizing with Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-login

I'm going to use Facebook JS SDK to login users to my site.

```
    function myLogin(){
        FB.api('/me',{fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
          if(response.email){

              //Ajax call function
              jQuery.ajax({ 
                  url: 'inc/social_logins/fb/account_auth.php',
                  type: "POST",
                  data: { func: 'nac', name: response.name, email: response.email},
                  success:function(data) {
                     if(data == 1){
                        window.location = "user_dashboard.php"; 
                     }
                  }
               });
               //Ajax call function ends

        }
    }
```

Above ajax request calls `account_auth.php` and it checks for accounts associated with the `email` comes with FB authorization. And if FB authorization returns true, it runs the `myLogin()` in the following logic.

```
 function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        qksellLogin();
    } 
  }
```

Everything works fine and gets redirected to the private dashboard area after FB login popup window closed.

What I want to do is, to block manual Ajax requests by unauthorized users.

Let's say if I can fake the response object and add someone else's FB `name` and `email`, then I call the above Ajax call function in the console, it still runs and logs in. That's terrible huh...

So, what actions may I want to take here ?

Comment: Send the access token to the backend. Fetch the data in the backend using the access token.

Comment: I'm actually new to this stuff. How to get access token ? How to send it ? What is it ?

Comment: Start reading:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v

Comment: @CBroe It's broken. Anyway, I have read these FB articles. I need some clarification in simple terms.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Access tokens are acquired by having the user log in to your app - so if that topic is completely new to you, you should start at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Thanks will do!!!